# Can I generate nonnegative solutions of a linear system?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a nonnegative (rectangular) matrix $A$ without rows containing only zero entries, a nonnegative vector $v$ and the following equation ($[*]$) where $u$ is the unknown vector:

$$Au = Av.$$

Let $w$ a nonnegative solution of $[*]$ different from $v$ and a matrix $S$ which spans the right nullspace of $A$ and generates $w$ the following form: $$w=v+Sq.$$ where $q$ is a nonnegative vector. I would like to ask if I can generate any nonnegative solution $z$ of $[*]$ different from $v$ with a nonnegative vector $p$ in the next form: $$z=v+Sp.$$

**Remarks to my question:**

1. Construct an arbitrary generator matrix of the right nullspace of $A$ denoted by $T$.
2. Find a nonnegative solution $w$ of the next form to $[*]$ where $r=$ {$r_{i}$} is a choosen (not necessarily nonnegative) coordinate vector: $$w=v+Tr.$$
3. Define $d_{i}$: $d_{i}=1$ if $r_{i}=0$; $d_{i}=sgn(r_{i})$ else ($sgn$ denotes the sign of its argument).
4. Construct a matrix denoted by $D$: $$D=diag(d_{i}).$$
5. Denote $TD$ by $S$.
6. Construct a vector $q$: $$q=D^{-1}r.$$
7. Substitute these symbols into the expression of $w$: 
   $$w=v+Tr=v+TDD^{-1}r=v+Sq.$$

Can this generator matrix $S$ fulfill those conditions wich can be found in my question?

Comment: This question stays, whether you want it or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will likely be negative entries in $S$, so $v+Sq$ is not guaranteed to be positive.  Also, there will be $p$ with negative entries that result in a nonnegative $v+Sp$.

Your solution space is a potentially infinite [convex polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polytope) of finite complexity.  This polytope is the intersection of all the half-spaces $x_i \ge 0$ (The nonnegative subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$) and the full solution space (without regard to sign) of $Ax = Av$.

This polytope will have a set of surface vertices and possibly some infinite edges, all of which will be rays.  You can then generate points in the nonnegative solution space by generating a point within the convex hull of the vertices and adding in a vector from a [conical combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conical_combination) of the direction vectors of the infinite edge rays.